# Rotation of view while dragging

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to slightly rotate a `UIView` when it's being dragged. I managed to do the dragging using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. I also tried to Rotate using `CGAffineTransformRotate` and it worked. However, when i apply both dragging and rotation, the `UIView` rotates only and it doesn't get dragged around the super view. Here is what i'm doing in the gesture handler:

```
CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];
    // to drag
    gesture.view.center = CGPointMake(gesture.view.center.x + translation.x, gesture.view.center.y + translation.y);
    // to rotate
    gesture.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(gesture.view.transform, degreesToRadians(translation.x)/4);
    // return to default so that it doesn't accumulate
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
```

How can i fix this ?

**EDIT:**
here is the entire code:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    // Save initial post center for snapping
    point = CGPointMake(gesture.view.center.x, gesture.view.center.y);
} else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
    // Translate user movement across the screen to dragging coordinates
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

    gesture.view.center = CGPointMake(gesture.view.center.x + translation.x, gesture.view.center.y + translation.y);

    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformRotate(gesture.view.transform, degreesToRadians(translation.x)/4);

    gesture.view.transform = rotate;//CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, rotate);

    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];


} else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
    // Animate snap back to place
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        gesture.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
       // [self.imagePost setCenter:point];
    }];
}
```

}

Comment: I understand you are not trying to rotate with two fingers, you just one the view to rotate as you pan it around. If that's the case that code you are posting works. So the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Odrakir the code above is being placed when the gesture recogniser state change, when i move the view it rotates but moving up or down it bounces in it's place. i'll post the entire code. i guess there isn't anything affecting the animation. Please check it in a minute

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
if (![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] && ![otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    return YES;
}

return NO;
```

}

Comment: No it doesn't work. i tried it as you posted it with UITapGestureRecognizer and then i tried it with UIPan as i'm using panning only also didn't work. i checked the delegation as well.

Comment: This should work. Try returning `YES` all of the time and see if it makes a difference. Also, have a look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more) for a tutorial which handles pan and pinch at the same time.

Comment: i tried returning YES it didn't work either. the rotation should occur simultaneously while dragging. there is no rotation gesture. i just drag left and right and it should slightly rotate while moving. Thanks anyway for your input